# What are these Disconnected notifications in the notification list?

Tags: gnome-shell, notification

I keep getting these "Disconnected" notifications throughout the day (even when I'm not using the computer), but I don't understand what's causing these notifications or what they mean. Clicking on any of the notifications just removes them from the notification list. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of notifications]

I don't recognize any of these names (i.e. `P.J. van Pelt`, `DESKTOP-GV09M8I`). None of the devices in our network have names like this. It's a little scary because it gives the impression that some remote desktop or device (e.g. hacker) is somehow connecting to my desktop. I double checked my settings and confirmed that remote desktop sharing is disabled. What does this notification mean?

Comment: Do you have or had other computers in the same network?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, there are other computers in the same network.

Comment: Then the first thing to do is to check their names. Very likely one will match and the disconnected message is showing up because at some point you tried to connect to that computer, either to a network share, a network printer connected to it or some sort of remote desktop. No, not an 'hacker'.

Comment: I personally configured all the other computers and printers in my network and none have a name that matches the one from the notification. It also doesn't match any network shares that I have. I don't use remote desktop on any of them either.

Comment: You live near a PJ van Pelt?  (Waddinxveen? Dordrecht? >:-D >:-D ) Maybe (s)he has a phone/tablet and computer with a open network. Or yours is open and PJ van Pelt is leeching. 1st thing to do: change your network password.

Comment: Do you recognize that name? But how would someone connecting to my Wifi network result in a notification on my GNOME desktop? That doesn't seem to make sense. I would only expect this notification when a device would connect to my desktop directly. Also, I have an overview of all devices that ever connected to my Wifi network, and these names don't appear there. Also, I'm not connected to any Wifi, I have a wired connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went to seek help on `#gnome` (`irc.gnome.org`) and thanks to a tip from **bluepenquin** I was able to solve this mystery.

I executed the following command in a terminal in order to see where the notifications are coming from:

```
dbus-monitor --session interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'
```

When the notification appeared again, I checked the output from this command. The output was as follows:

```
method call time=1661116961.269188 sender=:1.77 -> destination=:1.51 serial=353 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "blueman"
   uint32 0
   string "computer"
   string "DESKTOP-GV09M8I"
   string "Disconnected"
   array [
   ]
   array [
   ]
   int32 -1
```

In order to understand the meaning of this output, I looked up the [Desktop Notifications Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html). As you can see from the specification, the first component is the "Application Name"; this is the optional name of the application sending the notification. So these notifications come from the Blueman Bluetooth manager, and I have a Blueman applet that is always running in the top bar.

I then used Blueman to check the configuration of my Bluetooth adapters and found that one of my Bluetooth adapters was set to "Always visible". That means that anyone in the vicinity can connect to this Bluetooth adapter, and whenever they try to connect, this results in the above "Disconnected" notifications. So I changed the "Visibility setting" of the Bluetooth adapter to "Hidden", which should prevent random devices from connecting in the future.

I also checked to see what happens if someone successfully pairs via Bluetooth, and this cannot happen without authorization from me, so however these devices tried to connect, they didn't attempt a pairing, otherwise I would also get "Bluetooth Authentication" notifications, which I didn't get.