What is this notification that says "DELL LAPTOP Disconnected"?
I'm concerned, for the sake of security, about this notification.

It says "DELLLAPTOP" as the title, and the body says "Disconnected". That's all. I have no idea where it comes from. What app might it be? What does it even mean? Disconnected from what?
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. I do have a Dell laptop. I leave it connected to my 3 monitors 100% of the time. I think I only started seeing this message a few months ago. It's random when I'll see it, and it's rare. I detect no pattern as to when it shows... certainly not on any event that I'm aware of. I think it's usually when I return to my computer after it's had the monitors off, but yesterday it showed while I was actively using my computer.

Could it be a Bluetooth notification?

@Jos I don't think so. Bluetooth is on, but I've only connected to 3 things in the past, and I never connect to them anymore, and none have a name like DELLLAPTOP.

will this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423740/what-are-these-disconnected-notifications-in-the-notification-list

@amar Yes, that's it exactly! Thanks! So Jos was right. If anyone has the ability to close this question as a duplicate, please do so.
